# Reducing the Canvas drawing area,and fetching the coordinates on the canvas as a grid(or array of coordinates)?(Android)

Tags: android, android-canvas

Is it possible to reduce my drawing area of `Canvas` instead of making the whole screen available for drawing? I have placed `Button`s and `TextView`s, but apparently, I can draw over them. They don't hide, but behind them the `Canvas` gets colored.

And secondly, is it possible to retrieve all the coordinates of the `Canvas` as a grid(or array of coordinates)? Like:[image]

With coordinates filling the regions that is drawn upon, and other boxes of the grid being empty?

kindly help! :-)